# Getting bad request 400 error using asmack in android

Tags: android, xmpp, ejabberd, asmack

I am trying to register a new user using my XMPP client using asmack library in Android on ejabberd server. The problem is that I am getting following error & the user is not being created on the server:

```
bad-request(400)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.AccountManager.createAccount(AccountManager.java:243)
at in.ui.MainActivity$1$1$1.run(MainActivity.java:316)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Following is the code:

```
_xmppUsername = XMPPConfig.getStringUserInfoValue (XMPPConfig.XMPP_CLIENT_ID);
_xmppPassword = XMPPConfig.getStringUserInfoValue (XMPPConfig.XMPP_CLIENT_PASSWORD);
_xmppHost = XMPPConfig.getStringUserInfoValue (XMPPConfig.XMPP_HOST);
try {
    _xmppPortNo = Integer.parseInt (XMPPConfig.getStringUserInfoValue (XMPPConfig.XMPP_PORT));
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace ();
    Log.e (TAG, e.getMessage ());
}
_xmppServiceName = XMPPConfig.getStringUserInfoValue (XMPPConfig.XMPP_SERVICE_NAME);

ConnectionConfiguration conConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration (_xmppHost, _xmppPortNo, _xmppServiceName);

_xmppConnection = new XMPPConnection (conConfig);

if (!_xmppConnection.isAuthenticated ()) {
    login ();
}
/*
 * If connection has not been established or had been established &
 * broken again then login
 */

    @Override
    public void onShow (final DialogInterface dialog) {
        Button positiveButton = _dlgRegistration.getButton (DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
        positiveButton.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void onClick (View v) {

                // Creating registration thread
                new Thread (new Runnable () {
                    @Override
                    public void run () {
                        String clientID = null;
                        String password = null;

                            clientID = "user" + XMPP_SERVICE_NAME;
                            try {

                                // Getting hash password from UUID
                                password = "password";
                                Log.i (TAG, clientID + password);
                            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e1) {
                                e1.printStackTrace ();
                            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                                e1.printStackTrace ();
                            }
                        }
                        AccountManager manager = _xmppConnection.getAccountManager ();
                        try {


                                // Creating account on the server
                                manager.createAccount (clientID, password, attr);

                                                            }
                        } catch (XMPPException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace ();
                        }
                    }
                }).start ();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was this line `clientID = "user" + XMPP_SERVICE_NAME;` where I shouldn't have been appending Domain or Service Name after `"user"`.

Comment: Hey sorry to ask. 

you mentioned that { clientID = "user" + XMPP_SERVICE_NAME } where service name is not required.

But, in my case my username itself contains the structure like you mentioned above. 

I want my actual client i'd to be like this 

clientID = "abc@xyz.com" + XMPP_SERVICE_NAME

and if here I don't mention service name then my client I'D will be like this 

clientID = "abc@xyz.com"

and this means thet my user is "abc" and my service is "xyz.com".

Can you please help me with this how can I create user with the following format

user = abc@xyz.com

Thank You. :)