# XMPP jid-malformed(400) error Android while creating user

Tags: android, xmpp, chat, ejabberd, asmack

I am trying to develop XMPP chat in Android and while creating new user using AccountManager I am having the following exception :

> jid-malformed(400)

My user-connection code goes like this:

```
AccountManager manager = connection.getAccountManager();
try {
      manager.createAccount(username, password);
}
catch(XMPPException e){
   e..printStackTrace();
}
```

here my

```
username = abc@xyz.com  
password = 12345678
```

I learned that we need not require to send service name with the username from [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21597322/getting-bad-request-400-error-using-asmack-in-android)

But in my username the format says that my user is "abc" and my service is "xyz.com"

what should I do to keep '@' in my username?

Thank You. :)

Comment: check this link  [link](https://community.igniterealtime.org/thread/21161), it seems it worked for that guy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JID escaping is done as per [XEP-0106](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0106.html). Specifically, the "@" character should be replaced by "\40" to keep the "@" as part of the JID.